# Does FlowType support mixins or composition?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, flowtype, mixins

Does flow support mixins like the following?

```
// spark.js
import {includeEmitterIn} from 'emitter';
export default class Spark {
  constructor() {
    includeEmitterIn(this);
  }
  doSomething() {
    this.emit();
  }
}

// emitter.js
export function includeEmitterIn(obj) {
  obj.emit = function(callback) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With newer versions of Flowtype, you can now do mixins like so:

```
class A {}
class B {}

class C mixins A, B {}
```

Don't know what version this was introduced in though, sorry. The docs aren't the greatest, but I'm using this feature now.

edit: Looks like they were added in [0.16.0](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.16.0)